# Null Renderer not in graphedit

Tags: winapi, directshow

I'm running GraphEdit on Windows Server 2012 R2 and I've noticed that the null renderer is not there. There are some other directshow filters that I am using that will run in this server and the null renderer is the only one that isn't there.

I have registered quartz.dll and qedit.dll but there is still nothing.
How can I use the Null Render on Server 2012?

Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

Null Renderer (along with Sample Grabber and a few others) is hosted by qedit.dll, not quartz.dll. It looks like it is taken away from the most recent Windows versions and your best solution is to build your own. Windows SDK samples offers [Dump](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) sample (updated source code is [here in a fork](https://github.com/roman380/Windows-classic-samples/tree/directshow/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow)) which you can clean up to retain a doing nothing renderer.